# Conditionally select value of a column based on another column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query that at high level is something like this:

```
Select SomeColumns, LastName, StartDateString
from MyTable
```

Is it possible to have a logic in this select statement that can say print **for value of "StartDateString" column** the **"not started"** if `LastName` is for example **"abcd".** and print its real value otherwise.

Basically I want to know how to write a logic for output of one column based on value of some other column in the same row. ( I am using `SQL Server` )

Comment: Are you familiar with [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)?

Comment: @PM77-1 I didn't know I can act on value of one column based on value of another column.

Comment: SQL deals with **rows**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CASE`](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/case.php).

```
SELECT 
    SomeColumns,
    LastName, 
    CASE WHEN LastName = 'abcd' THEN 'Not Started'
         ELSE StartDateString END AS StartDateString
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: no sorry for confusion, This "Not Started" should show for "StartDateString" column.

Comment: updated to show StartDateString, note that this assumes StartDateString is a text type, otherwise you will have to cast it.

Answer (score 2):

Select SomeColumns, LastName, StartDateString ,(case when Lastname = 'abcd'+
  then 'not started' else 'started' +'on' + cast (StartDateString as varchar)  end) as **NewColumn**
from MyTable

Comment: I still want the real value of StartDateString for all other cases.

Comment: does that help?